# Python script not passing variable correctly

Tags: python, putty, plink

On the latest version of Debian 32-bit with Python 2.7.3, I've compiled Plink (part of the PuTTY suite of tools) from source.  For those unfamiliar, Plink is a great tool to issue commands on SSH servers so you can script your commands (I've found them wonderful for Cisco switches, which is what I'm doing here).

I have a file called **switch.list** containing names of switches on each line, such as:

```
Net-Switch-1
Net-Switch-2
Backbone-1
```

Now my Python script looks like this:

```
import subprocess

Switches = []
SwitchFile = open("switch.list")
for line in SwitchFile:
        Switches.append(line)
SwitchFile.close()

for sw in Switches:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["./plink","-ssh","-l","admin","-pw","REDACTED","-noagent","-batch",sw,"show","clock"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print p.communicate()
```

My output is:

```
Unable to open connection:
Name or service not known
('', None)
```

Over and over, for as many times as my switch count.  That tells me it's reading the file and populating the array just fine, but the Plink for-loop is messed up.

*Troubleshooting*: If I replace **sw** with a hard-coded switch name, like **Net-Switch-1**, then it runs fine.  This is why I know the variable, sw, isn't being passed along correctly.

*More Troubleshooting*: If I run the Plink command from CLI, omitting the switch name, I get the same error output, but without the third line of "*('', None)*"

*Troubleshooting where I start to get tricky*: This doesn't work either:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(["./plink","-ssh","-l","admin","-pw","REDACTED","-noagent","-batch",(" "+sw),"show","clock"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Don't open files like this: `SwitchFile =  open("switch.list")`. Do it like this instead: `with open("switch.list") as SwitchFile: # Indented code follows where you do file operations. No need to call .close()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading from file, lines contain the terminating new-line character. Try this instead:

```
for line in SwitchFile:
    Switches.append(line.strip())
```

Note also, that the common practice is to call variables with lower-case names.

Comment: This is a comment, much as I agree.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Why a comment? It is the answer to the question - because of the new-line the parameter is being passed incorrectly, so this is the solution.

Comment: Sorry, haven't finished reading the question till you posted the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the file correctly? If the info in the file is separated by newlines, Try something different like.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines() #extracts to a list.
print data
```